# how to display method name and the class name in gdb

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nslog

Hi all i am working on new app from  the beginning.upto now i am using nslog function call to display the output on the gdb.but from the some samples providing me the gdb display with the class and method names.i posted some screenshot for that.can any one guide me to take method name and display name while using nslog().

[image: getting class name and method name with the log]

please provide me some information.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"the method is %s", __func__);
```

__func__ is a builtin macro that expands to the current function or class+method name (it's a standard C string, hence the `%s` formatter instead of `%@`).

Comment: but from the above example those are not using NSLog(@"the method is %s", __func__); to get class and method name.is anything possible with the FKLog.h instead of using nslog.

Comment: Try it; it will display the class name and method name in the format you posted (edited my answer to make it clear).

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer.can you please provide some more information.This is like explicit calling and In the above example i am just writing nslog(@"trying to animate singletap") and i am found display as shown above for the first nslog.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following:

```
NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

This will dynamically generate both the class name and method name similar to `__func__`. If you're using Xcode 3.x, what I did was map Command-Option-L to the following user script that inserts a standard logging call like above:

[image]

Comment: what is use to do like this.Is there any advantage to do like this.

Comment: cant we print without calling __fun__.why i am asking this question is in the above screen shot gdb while printing i am using only nslog and not calling __fun__.

Answer (score 1):

this will easily print whatever method it is put in...

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```